# Determine if Age is between two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to determine what the ages in a dataframe are that fall between 0 and 10. I have written the following, but it only returns 'Yes' even though not all values fall between 1 and 10:

```
x = df['Age']

for i in x :
    if df['Age'].between(0, 10, inclusive=True).any():
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

I am doing this with the intention of creating a new column in the dataframe that will categorize people based on whether they fall into an age group, i.e., 0-10, 11-20, etc...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `.any()` is true if the condition is true in any row. Use `.all()` if you want to know if it's true for all values.

Comment: You're testing the entire dataframe each time through the loop, not row `i`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new column, assign to the column:

```
df['Child'] = df['Age'].between(0, 10, inclusive=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

> with the intention of creating a new column in the dataframe that will
> categorize people based on whether they fall into an age group, i.e.,
> 0-10, 11-20, etc...

Then [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) is what you are looking for:

```
pd.cut(df['Age'], list(range(0, df['Age'].max() + 10, 10)))
```

For example:

```
df['Age'] = pd.Series([10, 7, 15, 24, 66, 43])
```

then the above gives you:

```
0     (0, 10]
1     (0, 10]
2    (10, 20]
3    (20, 30]
4    (60, 70]
5    (40, 50]
```